# Navigate through multiple divs using next/prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically my DIV will look like this.

```
<div id="group">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="two">two</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="three">three</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="four">four</div>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
<div style="display:none" id="prev">prev</div>
<div style="display:none" id="prev">SUBMIT</div>
```

This is just an example, I could even have 10 or 20 divs.

I want to navigate from one to four in this example. When it reaches end it must hide the `next` button and show `submit` button. And when I navigate back to first page it must hide the `prev` button

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    $("#prev").show();
    $("#one").hide();
    $("#one").addClass("current");
    $(".current").next().addClass("current").show();
    $(".current").prev().removeClass("current").hide();
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    $("#prev").show();
    $("#one").hide();
    $("#one").addClass("current");
    $(".current").prev().addClass("current").show();
    $(".current").next().removeClass("current").hide();
});
```

This works for certain navigation after that it gets messes up. Some guidance will be helpful to me and others.

Thanks

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/450/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have an answer, but I would suggest a more structured approach that reuses a single code path:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aVJBY/460/

```
function updateItems(delta)
{
    var $items = $('#group').children();
    var $current = $items.filter('.current');
    var index = $current.index();
    var newIndex = index+delta;
    // Range check the new index
    newIndex = (newIndex < 0) ? 0 : ((newIndex > $items.length) ? $items.length : newIndex); 
    if (newIndex != index){
        $current.removeClass('current');
        $current = $items.eq(newIndex).addClass('current');
        // Hide/show the next/prev
        $("#prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));    
        $("#next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));    
    }
}
$("#next").click(function () {
    updateItems(1);
});
$("#prev").click(function () {
    updateItems(-1);
});
```

**Notes:**

- The range capping can be simplified, but you get the idea.
- You do not need to initial *inline* styling as that can be done in the CSS.
- This is not limited in any way by the content. Here I added 6 more divs: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aVJBY/463/

### Update

As I do not like situations where styling is required for initial "state" in a page, here is a new version that sets the initial state correctly too without *any* initial styling (using a 0 delta). I also removed a redundant var:

```
function updateItems(delta)
{
    var $items = $('#group').children();
    var $current = $items.filter('.current');
    $current = $current.length ? $current : $items.first();
    var index = $current.index() + delta;
    // Range check the new index
    index = (index < 0) ? 0 : ((index > $items.length) ? $items.length : index); 
    $current.removeClass('current');
    $current = $items.eq(index).addClass('current');
    // Hide/show the next/prev
    $("#prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));    
    $("#next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));    
}
$("#next").click(function () {
    updateItems(1);
});
$("#prev").click(function () {
    updateItems(-1);
});
// Cause initial selection
updateItems(0);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aVJBY/468/

Comment: I just noticed the answer marked use the DIV four , let me check your solution

Comment: perfect solution , This will help many , Because out in internet all are complex for this simple task..+1

Comment: Hey I have one question , How to find if its end or beginning  ? I would like to add some extra buttons on end and beginning

Comment: This should be pretty clear if you understood the code above..
Maybe this is a bit clearer to read for non-experienced ppl:http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/465/

Comment: @Vishnu: `$current.is($items.first())` says "is the first selected". `$current.is($items.last())` says "is the last selected". Save those values instead to a var if you want to use them more the once :)

Comment: Hey @TrueBlueAussie why does div inside this div is not visible , Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/469/

Comment: @Vishnu: It is hidden by the default `div` style I added in the CSS. Add an immediate child selector (`>`) to the CSS like this http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aVJBY/470/ You are better off using classes on all the divs instead

Comment: hey @TrueBlueAussie , I am sorry to bother you ,One last question. How can i reset it , i,e..Like move to the first page.

Comment: @Vishnu: You just need to remove the `current` class and call updateItems with 0 again. e.g. `$('#group .current').removeClass('current');` followed by `updateItems(0);`

Comment: How can I accomplish this, using a keypress instead of clicking on "Prev" and "Next", and make it stop at the last div, instead of keep scrolling through them?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe help you below code.

Updated... again...

```
$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    if($(".current").length!=1){
        $( "#group:first-child" ).addClass("current");
    }

    $(".current").removeClass("current").hide().next().addClass("current").show(); 

    if($(".current").next().length!=1){
        $( "#next" ).hide();
    }

    $( "#prev" ).show();  
});


$( "#prev" ).click(function() {
    if($(".current").length!=1){
        $( "#group:last-child" ).addClass("current");
    }

    $(".current").removeClass("current").hide().prev().addClass("current").show(); 

    if($(".current").prev().length!=1){
        $( "#prev" ).hide();
    }

    $( "#next" ).show();
});
```

[Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jckim0414/aVJBY/475/)

Comment: Its working but when it reaches "four" , it still shows next button , and same when it reaches "one" it shows prev button

Comment: My answer is updated check again ... i had some miss

Comment: hey am sorry , why do u use DIV four ? I told  I could even have 10 or 20 divs

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to suggest this approach though as I see the problem's been solved:

```
var $divs = $("#group").children("div"),
    index = 0;

$("#next").click(function () {
    updateStatus(1);
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    updateStatus(-1);
});

function updateStatus(a) {

    $divs.eq(index).removeClass("current").hide();
    index += a;
    $divs.eq(index).addClass("current").show();

    $("#next").toggle(index !== $divs.length - 1);
    $("#prev").toggle(index !== 0);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/471/)

Comment: I see you were thinking along the same lines I was. Suggest you start using `divs.eq(index)` rather than `$(divs[index])` in your jQuery though. Also "add" and "minus" as strings??? Missed a trick there (+1/-1) :)

Comment: yes, good point. I also like you'r way of using delta, I should have come up with that! well done

Comment: if you don't mind, I'm going to copy your delta idea and paste it on my code, the eq is something good too, but sometimes a bit obscure... Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to improve your code with ideas from mine. Learning is what SO is all about :) P.S. `.eq()` is definitely more readable in this instance (and shorter)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes, I think you're right, `eq` is the way to go. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also you should use `toggle(boolean)` to avoid using `hide` and `show` separately. No ternary operators needed then :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie another good point! Always willing to reduce code :) Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I am showing another approach where you can set the **current item to any element**, and it will show the `next prev` arrows accordingly.

```js
$(function() {
  var updateDiv = function(trigger) {
    var currentDiv = $(".current");
    $("#group div").removeClass("current").hide();
    if (trigger.hasClass("next") && currentDiv.next("div").length > 0) {
      currentDiv.next("div").addClass("current").show();
    } else if (trigger.hasClass("prev") && currentDiv.prev("div").length > 0) {
      currentDiv.prev("div").addClass("current").show();
    }
    updateNavigation();
  };

  var updateNavigation = function() {
    var intialDiv = $(".current");
    intialDiv.show();
    var intialDivIndex = intialDiv.index();
    intialDivIndex > 0 ? $("#prev").show() : $("#prev").hide();
    intialDivIndex < totalDivs - 1 ? $("#next").show() : $("#next").hide();
  };

  var totalDivs = $("#group div").length;
  updateNavigation();
  $("#next, #prev").on("click", function() {
    updateDiv($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
#group div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#next {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">
  <div id="one" style="display:none">one</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="two">two</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="three">three</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="four" class="current">four</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="five">five</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="six">six</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="seven">seven</div>
  <div style="display:none" id="eight">eight</div>
</div>
<div id="next" style="display:none" class="next">next</div>
<div style="display:none" id="prev" class="prev">prev</div>
<div style="display:none" id="prev">SUBMIT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to hide or show the prev and next buttons on click. You can use the `.index()` function of jQuery to check if the current div is the first or last item inside the div#group

```js
$(function(){
  var $cur = $('#group .current');
  var $items = $('#group .item');
  
  function hideButtons() {
    $cur = $('#group .current');
    var index = $cur.index();
    if(index > 0) {
      $('#prev').show();
    } else {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }
    
    if(index < $items.length - 1) {
      $('#next').show();
    } else {
      $('#next').hide();
    }
    
    
  }
  
  hideButtons();
  
  $('#next').click(function(){
    $cur.next().addClass('current');
    $cur.removeClass('current');
    hideButtons();
  });
  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $cur.prev().addClass('current');
    $cur.removeClass('current');
    hideButtons();
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
  }

.item.current {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">
    <div id="one" class="current item">one</div>
    <div id="two" class="item">two</div>
    <div id="three" class="item">three</div>
    <div id="four" class="item">four</div>
</div>
<button id="next">next</button>
<button style="display:none" id="prev">prev</button>
```